# Embed Windows media player in flex

Tags: windows, apache-flex, flex4, windows-media-player

I have a mp4 file which is to be used in an application. Currently i am in the stage of figuring out the technology to be used for this job. I am familiar with flex and am hoping that i be able to use it for the application. But i can not figure out a way to play the file in flex. I have been able to play the file only in windows media player and that required the installation of three codecs : Mp4Audio.ax, Mp4Video.ax, Mp4Src.ax.

As i see it, it will be very convenient if i could embed a windows media player plugin in flex or i could specify the audio and video codecs in the flash player.
Else i will have to learn .Net, i guess.

Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating an air app then you are able to start the windows-media-player using the NativeProcess. Anyway if you have a flex web app then you do not have any options on this. :(

My recommendation: Convert the video file to a valid mp4 file that can be played by flex. I suggest you to check ffmpeg library (and you could use it to convert the file to H264 format)

Comment: thank you for the reply. I am actually looking at a desktop application. I would like to know if NativeProcess allows me to embed the player in the application (as i would like to place some components above it) or just to play the file by opening windows media player. Thanks

Comment: you cannot embed it. see the native process adobe help specs and this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html